# Enable php-intl in ISPConfig 3, Debian 8 and additional php 7.1 on server

Tags: php, debian, php-extension, ispconfig-3

How to enable php-intl on php7.1 with Debian 8 + ISPConfig 3.x. It says, that it's installed on php7.1 but it is not enabled.
If I run

```
./php --ri intl
```

I will get "Extension 'intl' not present."